# Exclude a file or directory from CODEOWNERS

Tags: github, github-codeowners

I have a file structure like so:

```
foo/file1.c
foo/file2.c
foo/freeforall.c
```

My `foogroup` on GitHub needs to review changes to everything in `foo` **except** `freeforall.c` which is a file that anyone can touch without restriction, so it should not automatically add anybody as a reviewer when changes are made to it.

(In reality, whoever modifies `freeforall.c` just asks someone else on their own team to review their change.)

## The Question

How can I do this with GitHub CODEOWNERS? The file looks like this right now:

```
foo @MyOrg/foogroup
```

## What I Tried

[GitHub explicitly says](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) that the `!` syntax is not supported, so that won't work:

```
foo @MyOrg/foogroup
!foo/freeforall.c
```

And there are too many files in the `foo` directory to explicitly include them individually. I *could* move `freeforall.c` into a different directory, but *really* I don't want to be having GitHub's CODEOWNER feature dictating how I organize my components. I *want* `freeforall.c` to be in the `foo` directory, that's where it belongs!

I also considered creating an `emptygroup` to assign that file to, but soon realized that now I'd be requiring that *a group with zero members* must approve PRs to that file which obviously would cause problems.

```
foo @MyOrg/foogroup
foo/freeforall.c @MyOrg/emptygroup
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `CODEOWNERS` file takes the last matching line into account. You can make definitions with empty owners to specify paths/files without an owner.

Consequently, you can use the following lines to have all files in the `foo` directory owned by `@MyOrg/foogroup` except `foo/freeforall.c`:

```
foo @MyOrg/foogroup
foo/freeforall.c
```

Comment: AFAIK, the order is also important, because CODEOWNERS is read from bottom to top, and once a entry that determines the ownership of a file is found, the search for that file ownership is over. Therefore, place the entry for the ignored file **below** the entry defining ownership for the whole folder.